# Current in an open circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis

The argument that was presented to me was that at node N, i2 + i3 = 0 since it is an open circuit. I do not understand this argument, if there is no current at the positive terminal, than how can there be a voltage change across the circuit? Could someone help clarify this?

[image]

Comment: Write the KVL equation around that bottom-right loop and you will see

Comment: Voltage is comparable to pressure, current is flow.  You can have pressure without flow, same as you can apply physical pressure to an object and not have it move.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

KCL at node N tells us that i2 + i3 must equal zero. We don't talk about current **at**, we talk about current **through**. Even there is no current through node A **directly** to node B, the current flowing in other parts of the circuit will cause a difference in voltage between A and B. That's just how circuits work.

I hope that this is enough of a hint that you can finish the problem.

Comment: Consider a battery. There is a voltage between its terminals even though no current is flowing.

Answer (score 3):

Voltage between terminals exists even if it a open circuit, because there is a potential difference between the two open circuited nodes.
If the circuit is considered to be grounded at any point then there definitely exists a potential difference. For current to flow there must be a path for the electrons. in open circuit condition, that path is not provided. Hence current cannot flow.

Answer (score 1):

Vo could have a non-zero value, but in this circuit with these values, Vo is zero volts.  I2 is 1/20 of an amp and I3 is zero amps.

Comment: Original answers... of which the first is correct but the second is not...

Comment: Please don't hand out solutions to homework problems. That's not what we do here.

Answer (score 0):

I3=0 but i2 contains a finite value which is easily calculated by loop/mesh analysis.  The current through the 100 ohm resistor plus the -5 volts source brings Vo to zero volts.

Comment: You should just write one answer. Edit that answer if necessary, but don't add multiple answers.

Comment: Just to add that this is not an explicit order but only a wish. Maybe, the point of this is not to accumulate more votes from the same person.

Answer (score 0):

What is the difference between a computer and a human if we show them an unfamiliar circuit diagram like this? The computer will begin to blindly analyze it through formal rules while the person will first try to find something familiar in it... And because we are human beings and not computers, let's do just that. So what do we see in the diagram?

First, we see two grounded voltage sources producing voltages with opposite polarities.

They are connected to each other by two resistor paths in parallel. The first - 100 ohm resistor in the left, is not interesting because it does not affect the rest of the circuit.

However, the network of the other two resistors (200 and 100 ohm) in series is something more interesting. Let's see why.

Basically, this is a *voltage divider* "stretched" between two opposite voltage sources. So actually it is a *resistor summing circuit* with weighted inputs  that sum two opposite voltages according to the superposition principle. As a result, we obtain the well-known proportion V2/V1 = 10/5 = R2/R1 = 200/100 = 2 and Vo = 0.

We can see this proportion in the circuit of an *op-amp inverting amplifier* where Vin = -5 V, Vout = 10 V, and Vo = 0 V is the voltage of the so-called *virtual ground*.

By the way, there is another "virtual ground" somewhere inside the 100 ohm resistor "stretched" between the voltage sources. We can "see" (measure) it if we remove the insulation coating of the resistive film.

Now let's say something about the currents. Again, i1 is not interesting; it flows from V2 (10 V) to V1 (-5 V). More interesting are i2 and i3. Actually, they are equivalent: i2 flows, like i1, from V2 (10 V) to the N node and then, i3 flows from N to V1 (-5 V). Thus i1 enters N, while i3 exits N... and the true i3 direction is opposite. For the purposes of (intuitively) understanding circuits, we need true current directions and true voltage polarities (when possible).

I was just thinking out loud...